# How can I change the precision of printing with the stl?

Tags: c++, precision, iostream

I want to print numbers to a file using the stl with the number of decimal places, rather than overall precision.

So, if I do this:

```
int precision = 16;
std::vector<double> thePoint(3);
thePoint[0] = 86.3671436;
thePoint[1] = -334.8866574;
thePoint[2] = 24.2814;
ofstream file1(tempFileName, ios::trunc);
file1 << std::setprecision(precision)
    << thePoint[0]  << "\\"
    << thePoint[1]  << "\\"
    << thePoint[2] << "\\";
```

I'll get numbers like this:

```
86.36714359999999\-334.8866574\24.28140258789063
```

What I want is this:

```
86.37\-334.89\24.28
```

In other words, truncating at two decimal points.  If I set precision to be 4, then I'll get

```
86.37\-334.9\24.28
```

ie, the second number is improperly truncated.

I do not want to have to manipulate each number explicitly to get the truncation, especially because I seem to be getting the occasional 9 repeating or 0000000001 or something like that that's left behind.

I'm sure there's something obvious, like using the printf(%.2f) or something like that, but I'm unsure how to mix that with the stl << and ofstream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use std::fixed , this should work for you.

```
 file1 << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision)
     << thePoint[0]  << "\\"
     << thePoint[1]  << "\\"
     << thePoint[2] << "\\";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
file1 << std::setiosflags(ios::fixed) << std::setprecision(precision)
```

which sets fixed-point format instead of floating-point.

(By the way, this is not [STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html). It's [iostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/).)

…Oh! I think Kumar bettered me with `std::fixed`.

Comment: Just because something uses templates doesn't make it STL. Follow the links and you will find they are radically different.